# tinymce inline editor binding for loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tinymce

I'm trying to make an e-mail template builder and I'm using tinyMCE 4.3.2.
I need a simple solution about binding editor to a div.

Steps :

1) I load an HTML block by using jquery.load

2) I look in this loaded HTML block and I give it a unique id (like `id-234234324`)

3) Then I bind the tinyMCE "inline" editor to this div.

It works correctly.

But when my loaded HTML block contains a "TABLE", TinyMCE not binding to resize actions for table cell.

Codes:
1) I'm dragging an item to template area

```
function draggingEnds(ui, templatePath, editorType) {

$(ui.helper).load(templatePath, '', function (body) {
    var rand = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000).toString();
    var newId = 'id-' + rand;
    $(body).insertAfter($(ui.helper)).find("div").attr("id", newId);
    $(ui.helper).remove();
    $("#template > *").bind("mouseover");
    bindSortable();
    if (editorType != "none") { bindEditor(newId, editorType); };
});};
```

2) Then I'm binding inline tinyMCE editor by using `bindEditor()` function

```
function bindEditor(id) {

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#' + id,
    language: 'tr',
    inline: true,
    plugins: 'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste',
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
});}
```

3) Loaded HTML

```
<li>
<aside class="item-actions">
    <span class="handle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i> Taşı</span>
    <span class="copy" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Kopyala</span>
    <span class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Sil</span>
</aside>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, tinyMCE not set "resizing actions" for cells:

[image]